# How to convert my old projects structure to the new Codenameone initializer project structure based on maven?

Tags: codenameone

We have been writing a Code Name One project since a few years ago.
It is already in production.
The project was created using IDE Netbeans which creates all the initial folder structures for it.
Recently, Codenameome provide an app called Codenameone initializ which executes the task of creating a new project from scratch using a new folder structure and using maven as dependencies manager.

We want to convert our project to this new structure and use it from now on.

How could We do that?
Is there a converter for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the tutorial here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-your-project-to-maven.html

Personally I prefer creating a new project then copying the source files and my personal build hints. Then adding the dependencies. This keeps the project "clean" and helps remove a lot of the legacy stuff from over the years.

This is important since a lot of things changed significantly. E.g. dependency hints are no longer listed in `codenameone_settings.properties` and are instead listed in the individual dependency. So the file is cleaner.